# How to find multiple keywords in a string column in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a column

```
|ABC|
-----
|JWUFT_P_RECF_1_DK1_VWAP_DFGDG_P_REGB_1_PK1_XYZ|
```

i WANT TO CHECK IF THERE ARE WORDS "DK" AND 'PK' in the row or not. i need to perform this with different words in entire column.

```
match = ['DK', 'PK']
```

i used `df.ABC.str.split('_').isin(match)`,  but it splits into list but getting error

> SystemError: <built-in method view of numpy.ndarray object at
> 0x0000021171056DB0> returned a result with an error set

What is the best way to get the expected output, which is a bool True|False

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe either of the two following options:

```
(?:[A-Z\d]+_)*?([DP]K)\d*_(?:[A-Z\d]+_)*?(?!\1)([DP]K)\d*(?:_[A-Z\d]+)*?
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KyqtsT/10

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ABC': ['JWUFT_P_RECF_1_DK1_VWAP_DFGDG_P_REGB_1_PK1_XYZ']})
df['REX_TEST'] = df.REX_TEST.str.match(r'(?:[A-Z\d]+_)*?([DP]K)\d*_(?:[A-Z\d]+_)*?(?!\1)([DP]K)\d*(?:_[A-Z\d]+)*?')
print(df)
```

---

Or, add leading/trailing underscores to your data before matching:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ABC': ['JWUFT_P_RECF_1_DK1_VWAP_DFGDG_P_REGB_1_PK1_XYZ']})
df['REX_TEST']= '_' + df.ABC + '_'
df['REX_TEST'] = df.REX_TEST.str.match(r'(?=.*_PK\d*_)(?=.*_DK\d*_).*')
print(df)
```

---

Both options print:

```
                                              ABC  REX_TEST
0  JWUFT_P_RECF_1_DK1_VWAP_DFGDG_P_REGB_1_PK1_XYZ      True
```

---

Note that I wanted to make sure that both 'DK' nor 'PK' are a substring of a larger word.

Comment: Well, 2nd one does work, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use python re library to search a string:

```
import re
s = "JWUFT_P_RECF_1_DK1_VWAP_DFGDG_P_REGB_1_PK1_XYZ"
r = re.search(r"(DK).*(PK)|(PK).*(DK)",s) # the pipe is used like "or" keyword
```

If what your parameters are matched with the string it will evaluate to True:

```
if r:
    print("hello world!")
```